# Why isnt my Android module Activity found in Merged AndroidManifest from Main App?

Tags: android, android-manifest

My current Android Application has a main App and multiple UI modules,

I am trying to start a UI module Activity from my main App as follows...

```
 activity.startActivity(Intent().setClassName(it.screen.packageName(), it.screen.className()))
```

the exception I see is

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {org.research.development.ui_module_a/org.research.development.ui_module_a.ModuleAScreenOneActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I thought all `AndroidManifiest` files were merged into one, so surely at runtime theres one manifest file and it will hold all activities?

Is it not possible to start a module Activity using package name and class name as strings?

Is my only option to use Action Intent filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought all AndroidManifiest files were merged into one, so surely at runtime theres one manifest file and it will hold all activities?

They are. You can check this on Android Studio by opening your main manifest file (usually located under app/) and selecting the "merged manifest" tab.

It's likely that you're not setting the class name and package name correctly. To illustrate, let's say I have the app module (the main one) and another module, mymodule. The app module depends on this one. Let's also say this is a debug build and we have the ".debug" suffix configured. In this case the values would be

```
package = "com.mypackage.debug"
classname = "com.mypackage.somethingonmymodule.MyActivity"
```

So the package should be your app's package as seen by the OS (and defined in the end manifest that's bundled with the apk) and the class name the fully qualified package as you define it in your codebase. Both these values should be visible in the merged manifest view (as mentioned above).

Alternatively, if the app module depends on mymodule, you can build your Intent in a different way:

```
Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java)
```

Comment: my mistake was using the modules package name and not the Apps one. Thanks for your help, and showing me theres a merged tab for AndroidManifest file.